# SAS Macro Query

Tags: macros, sas, ods

I am having trouble with the following %macro for a regression.

Basically, I want it to run whenever i=j, and i=1 to 12 and j=1 to 12.

```
  %macro reg(num=);
    %do i=1 %to &num;
    %do j=1 %to &num;
    proc reg data=ccy.eur; *Specify Currency Data Set Here;
    model Ft_leadSt&i = Ft_St&j;
    where &i=&j;
    ods output parameterestimates (persist) =dpara1;
    run;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;
%reg(num=12)
```

The problem is my output seems to stop when i=9 and j=9. I haven't been able to figure out why?

[image]

Screen Shot of data

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshot of the input also would be helpful, looks like there are no matches after 'dpara1' is 9.

Comment: Thans @Alam - Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite this without the double loop and only 1 `PROC REG` statement:

```
  %macro reg(num=);
    proc reg data=ccy.eur; *Specify Currency Data Set Here;
    ods output parameterestimates (persist) =dpara1;
    var FT_leads1 - FT_leads&n FT_St1 - FT_St&n;
    %do i=1 %to &num;
       _&i: model Ft_leadSt&i = Ft_St&i;
       run;
    %end;
    quit;
  %mend;
%reg(num=12)
```

Make sure you have those variables in the data set.

Comment: @dompass Thank you very much - I receive the following error message   ERROR: There were 1 unclosed %DO statements.  The macro REG will not be compiled.
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled.
1473  %reg(num=12)
      -
      180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro REG not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order

Comment: @wazza2013 sorry, I left out a `%end;`  I updated it for you.